# Dynamics CRM 2016 Online Security/Isolation Mode

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a simple post create plugin on the Account entity that makes a subsite in SharePoint online with the same name of the Account that has been created.

I have used the `SharePointOnlineCredentials` class from the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime` assembly to login to the SharePoint instance.

The plugin works on an on-premise instance as long as the plugin is set to `isolation mode = none`.

When I run the plugin in Sandbox isolation mode I get the error below (online version error).

I want to run this plugin on an online instance of SharePoint, but as, I believe, I cannot run online with an isolation mode = none, is there another way of running code using this SharePoint assembly on an online CRM instance?

> Message: Create, Method: ExecutePluginLogic Exception:
>   System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.    at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object
>   demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)    at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()    at
>   System.Net.AuthenticationManager.Register(IAuthenticationModule
>   authenticationModule)    at
>
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationModule.EnsureRegistered()
>      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials..ctor(String
>   username, SecureString password)    at
>
> MWLSPXRMToolkitOnline.Plugins.AccountCreate.ExecutePluginLogic(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)    at
>   MWLSPXRMToolkitOnline.Plugins.BasePlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)
>
> The action that failed was: Demand The type of the
>   first permission that failed was:
>
> System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission The Zone of the
>   assembly that failed was: MyComputer

Answer (score 1):

Not sensibly, when running in Sandbox mode you can't include references to other assemblies. You could try using ILMerge to combine the assemblies together, but if I was you I would take a different approach, e.g. pushing work to an external web service.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I will take the external web service approach you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If  using ILMerge  to combine the assemblies together(as recommended by James Wood because when running in Sandbox mode you can't include references), use the '/copyattrs' parameter with ILMerge.
If you have installed ilMarge in the project with NuGet package:

Editing the file in solution:ILMerge.props
Change parameters:

```
<ILMergeAllowMultipleAssemblyLevelAttributes>true</ILMergeAllowMultipleAssemblyLevelAttributes>
<ILMergeCopyAttributes>true</ILMergeCopyAttributes>
```